# How to create a Key Vault Managed Storage Account in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template that creates a storage account and a key vault:

```
...
{
    "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "name": "mystorageaccountname",
    "location": "canadacentral",
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
    },
    "kind": "StorageV2",
    "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
    }
}
...

...

{
    "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
    "name": "mykeyvault",
    "location": "canadacentral",
    "properties": {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "sku": {
            "family": "A",
            "name": "standard"
        },
        "accessPolicies": []
    }
}
...
```

I would like for my [Key Vault to manage the storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys). Unfortunately for me, the [examples](https://cloudexcite.com/azure-how-to-create-a-key-vault-managed-storage-account/) I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547394/azure-storage-account-with-key-vault-to-manage-its-keys) so far are Powershell scripts.

In the [ARM template documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2019-09-01/vaults), it is not clear to me how I could implement such a thing.

**Question**

How can I configure the key vault in the ARM template to manage the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

Until some time, there was no possibility to do such a thing as ARM Templates didn't support creating Azure KV keys directly from them. Recently there was an update posted, that it's finally available:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', parameters('keyName'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "kty": "[parameters('keyType')]",
                "keyOps": "[parameters('keyOps')]",
                "keySize": "[if(equals(parameters('keySize'), -1), json('null'), parameters('keySize'))]",
                "curveName": "[parameters('curveName')]"
            }
        }
```

You see the full example here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-template?tabs=CLI. With that you are able to just reference a Storage Account key value and put it directly into Azure Key Vault. You can try to do that using that structure:

```
[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]
```